# Remove whitespace and preserve \n \t .. etc

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

How do I preserve line breaks, tab, ...etc from a text? Currently, I can take out extra white spaces in the text document, along with that it also removes \n, \t, unicodes, ...etc.

```
text = 'Hello world \n I wrote some random    text    here \t \n\n. I am trying      to remove extra whitespace but keep line breaks, tabs, ...etc'
text = re.sub( '\s+', ' ', text).strip()
print(text)
print(type(text))
```

I tried this but doesn't help.

```
import textwrap
textwrap.wrap(text,80,replace_whitespace=True)
```

Current Output:

```
Hello world I wrote some random text here . I am trying to remove extra whitespace but keep line breaks, tabs, ...etc
<class 'str'>
```

Needed Output:

```
Hello world \n I wrote some random text here \t \n\n. I am trying to remove extra whitespace but keep line breaks, tabs, ...etc
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You told the regular expression to match *all whitespace*, not just spaces. Don't use `\s` if you only want to match spaces, use an actual space:

```
text = re.sub(' +', ' ', text).strip()
```

Demo:

```
>>> import re
>>> text = 'Hello world \n I wrote some random    text    here \t \n\n. I am trying      to remove extra whitespace but keep line breaks, tabs, ...etc'
>>> re.sub(' +', ' ', text).strip()
'Hello world \n I wrote some random text here \t \n\n. I am trying to remove extra whitespace but keep line breaks, tabs, ...etc'
```

From the [*Regular Expression Syntax* section of the `re` module documenation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax), on the `\s` sequence meaning:

> `\s`
>
> Matches Unicode whitespace characters (which includes `[ \t\n\r\f\v]`, and also many other characters, for example the non-breaking spaces mandated by typography rules in many languages). If the ASCII flag is used, only `[ \t\n\r\f\v]` is matched.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `re.split` and `join`:

```
>>> ' '.join(re.split(r'[ ]{2,}', text))
'Hello world \n I wrote some random text here \t \n\n. I am trying to remove extra whitespace but keep line breaks, tabs, ...etc'
```

The key element is the regex `[ ]{2,}` that splits on runs of actual `' '` space characters longer than 2 spaces long.

You can use the same regex with `re.sub`:

```
>>> re.sub(r'[ ]{2,}', ' ', text)
'Hello world \n I wrote some random text here \t \n\n. I am trying to remove extra whitespace but keep line breaks, tabs, ...etc'
```